# I want to insert multiple values which includes two arrays(of strings) in a single INSERT statement into a table of mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert multiple values which includes two arrays(of strings) in a single `INSERT` statement into a table of mysql in php.

I want to use prepared statement.can you suggest how can I do this?

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO swaasthadata (name, age, email, gender, address, phone, mobile, catagory) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO swaasthadata (name, age, email, gender, address, phone, mobile, catagory) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sisssiis",$name,$age,$email,$gender,$address,$phone,$mobile,$catagory);

$stmt->execute();
```

with this two arrays of strings have to be inserted in the table like this.
`$array1()` and `array2()`

But my question is to insert all those in a single query since these all data fields are there in database table.Is it possible?
Please how can I do this?

Comment: replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` and you will see errors. [Because, `name` will give you a hard time.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)

Comment: plus why do you have this line `$sql= "INSERT INTO swaasthadata...`? it doesn't do anything. Here, for you W3 schools lovers http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp - *grin* and for true hardcore coders http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: The above insert statement works fine.Along with it I want to send two arrays to the same table.How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code and it is working fine and inserting into the database.
$array1=implode(",",$pack);
$array2=implode(",",$test);

where $pack and $test are arrays of strings.

$stmt=$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO table (name, age, email, gender, address, phone, mobile, catagory, packagename, testname) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$stmt-->bind_param("sisssiisss",$name,$age,$email,$gender,$address,$phone,$mobile,$catagory,$array1,$array2);

$success=$stmt->execute();

Comment: But while executing this before entering and submitting the form,I'm getting an error "column packagename cannot be null,column testname cannot be null".packagename and testname are column names in the table.How to solve this?Pl help